# 9-regular graph with 100 vertices

Tags: graph-theory, pigeonhole-principle, coloring

> Prove that every simple 9-regular graph on 100 vertices contains a
>   subgraph with maximum degree at most 5 and at least 225 edges.

**My attempt**

I think I should use the pigeonhole principle but I don't know how.

I thought maybe to take 2 subgraphs that complete each other to the whole graph and in one of them the maximum degree has to be 5 (if in both of them it's above 5 than the maximum degree of the whole graph is above 10).
but how do I know that this subgraph has also at least 225 edges?

I'm not sure that is necessarily true.
I'd like to get some help here,
thank you!

Comment: You can have two edge-disjoint subgraphs that both have maximal degree $>5$, just not at thee same vertex...

Comment: Given that the graph contains $100*9/2=450$ edges, it does seem like the way to go is to construct two complementary graphs, both with maximal degree 5. Then at least one of them has at least $225$ edges. So is there always an edge 2-colouring such that every vertex has 4 of one of the colours and 5 of the other? I have no idea.

Answer (score 5):

By [Vizing’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vizing%27s_theorem)  there exists a proper edge-coloring of the graph in 10 colors. So there exist 5 colors coloring at least $(100\cdot 9/2)\cdot 5/10=225$ edges. The graph with these edges has maximal vertex degree at most 5.

Comment: Very nice!${}{}{}{}{}$